# ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor when deploy:assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I have problem with deploy rails application to server. 
When I try deploy in step `deploy:assets:precompile` I get

```
 01 rake aborted!
  01 ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
  01 /var/www/spycommerce/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in _decrypt'
  ...
  01
  01 Caused by:
  01 OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError:
  01 /var/www/spycommerce/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:201:in `final'
  ...
```

When I try compile assets  manual `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` I not get error

Capfile

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/puma'

install_plugin Capistrano::Puma  # Default puma tasks

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

versions

```
rails -v => 5.2.1
capistrano -v => 3.11
```

I try fix with `config.require_master_key = true`, and create link `set :linked_files, %w{config/master.key}` in deploy.rb. nothing helps

Comment: You may have to post full backtrace

Comment: Can you also post `deploy.rb`

Comment: [capistrano.log](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Feboll/kezMR8)
[deploy.rb](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Feboll/qebRgG)

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Problem fixed when I reinit project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem when testing the MessageEncryptor for a Rails Api application from the command line. A solution to prevent the InvalidMessage exception: If You have to use ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor outside of the rails initialisation context, do manually set ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.use_authenticated_message_encryption = true. MessageEncryptor then use the intended default_cipher aes-256-gcm.